# ¿Cómo retornar un string desde un Task<string>?

Tags: c#, http-post

Estoy realizando un HttpRequest. Resulta que al retornar la respuesta y mostrarla para trabajarla, me muestra esto:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
```

Mi código es:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MLWPF.HttpRequest
{
    class Client
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private FormUrlEncodedContent content;

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Uid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public double Phone { get; set; }

        public Client()
        {

        }

        public Client(int id, int uid, string name, string address, double phone)
        {
            Id = id;
            Uid = uid;
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
            Phone = phone;
        }

        public async Task<string> ReadClients(int uid)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"uid", uid.ToString()}
            };

            content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new UrlHttpRequest().UrlReadClients, content);
            string responseString =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }

    }
}
```

Resulta que si muestro en consola antes de retornar el `responseString`, se muestra correctamente la información obtenida.

Lo estoy llamando desde un método en el MainWindow.xaml.cs conectado a un botón.

```
private void FAB_Tab1_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Client client = new Client(); 
    client.ReadClients(1); 
    Console.WriteLine(client.Name);
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al retornar obtenga la información que necesito?

Comment: Como estas llamando a este metodo?

Comment: @sstan muy probablemente lo este llamando con un Task.Run, y no con un await directo..

Comment: @sstan La pregunta no es mala, capaz confusa.. la respuesta tampoco, pero no soluciona el problema, porque apuesto rep a que el problema es la llamada a la funcion y no el retorno de la misma, que es correcto...

Comment: Estoy instanciando el método, quizá ahí tengo el problema. Lo llamo así ``Console.WriteLine(new Client().ReadClients(1))``

Comment: Eso no tira un warning enorme por llamar a un metodo asincronico sin un await?

Comment: si lo llamas como string s = await cli.ReadClients(1) deberia devolverte un string... no es cierto?

Comment: Cambie la forma en la que hago el request Estoy usando un WebRequest que encontré en la documentación de MS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP comenta:

> Estoy instanciando el método, quizá ahí tengo el problema. Lo llamo así `Console.WriteLine(new Client().ReadClients(1))`

En efecto, ese es el problema. Como `ReadClients` es un método `async`, para obtener el valor de vuelta, necesitas usar `await`:

```
Console.WriteLine(await new Client().ReadClients(1));
```

Sin embargo, si la llamada la estás haciendo desde el `main` por ejemplo, que no puedes marcar como `async`, entonces tendrías que hacer la llamada de esta forma:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(new Client().ReadClients(1).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
  }
```

Pero cabe notar que a partir de [C# 7.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main) sí es posible marcar el `main` con `async` de la siguiente forma:

```
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(await new Client().ReadClients(1));
  }
```

**Edición basado en el código que agregastes a tu pregunta**

Si estás tratando de hacer la llamada desde un event handler, debes agregar `async` a la firma del event handler y ejecutar `ReadClients` con `await`:

```
private async void FAB_Tab1_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Client client = new Client(); 
    await client.ReadClients(1); 
    Console.WriteLine(client.Name);
}
```

...o, si vuelves a tu versión original de `ReadClients` que devuelve directamente el resultado deseado (probablemente una buena idea), es básicamente lo mismo:

```
private async void FAB_Tab1_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(await new Client().client.ReadClients(1));
}
```

Comment: De esta forma si funciona, resulta que también estaba cometiendo un error enorme, estaba llamando al método Task desde un otro método "click" por eso no me permitía funcionar bien

Comment: De allí la importancia que esta clase de preguntas siempre incluya un verdadero [mcve]. Muchas veces el error no está donde uno piensa, y para evitar andar en la pista equivocada, es útil poder reproducir tu error.

Answer (score 5):

Una opción es utilizar el método [`Task.FromResult<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx), donde únicamente cambiarías `return responseString;` por `return Task.FromResult<responseString>;`, quedando tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
private FormUrlEncodedContent content;

public async Task<string> ReadClients(int uid)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"uid", uid.ToString()}
    };

    content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new UrlHttpRequest().UrlReadClients, content);
    string responseString =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Task.FromResult<responseString>;
}
```

O en su caso, cambiar la línea del `HttpResponseMessag response = ...` por `HttpResponseMessage response = await Task.FromResult<string>(httpClient.PostAsync(new UrlHttpRequest().UrlReadClients, content));`

```
private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
private FormUrlEncodedContent content;

public async Task<string> ReadClients(int uid)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"uid", uid.ToString()}
    };

    content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await Task.FromResult<string>(httpClient.PostAsync(new UrlHttpRequest().UrlReadClients, content));
    string responseString =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: al utilizar ``return Task.FromResult<responseString>`` me lanza un error ya que no reconoce responseString como una variable sino como tipo de dato. Al usar el segundo modo el sistema sugiere crear un ``await await Task.FromResult...`` en cualquier caso cuando instancio el método y muestro lo retornado me sigue indicando un Task y no un string, lo llamo de la siguiente manera ``Console.WriteLine(new Client().ReadClients(1)``. Insisto si muestro el contenido de ``responseString`` dentro del método el request funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré otra forma de obtener la información.
Para facilitar creé una nueva variable string dentro de la clase a la cual le asigno el `public string s = responseString;` entonces cuando instancio lo hago de una nueva manera.

```
Client client = new Client();
client.ReadClients();
Console.WriteLine(client.s);
```

De esta manera obtengo el contenido que regresa.

Comment: Si `ReadClients` sigue siendo un método `async`, entonces tu código no funcionará siempre. Tiene un *race condition*. O sea que no hay garantía que `ReadClients` haya completado su ejecución para cuando intentes leer `client.s`. Sigue siendo necesario que ejecutes `ReadClients` con `await`.

Comment: Estoy llamando de la siguiente forma, agregue un Thread.Sleep dentro del método Async para ver si tardaba y la me entregó la misma respuesta del tiempo necesario``private void FAB_Tab1_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.ReadClients(1);
            Console.WriteLine(client.Name);
        }``

Comment: El método es este.    ``private void FAB_Tab1_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { Client client = new Client(); client.ReadClients(1); Console.WriteLine(client.Name); }`` ahí hago el llamado, esta conectado a un boton

Comment: Acabo de hacer una edición a mi respuesta al respecto. Me basé en la versión anterior de `ReadClients` que sí devuelve de una vez el resultado. Si quieres separar la lectura del resultado de la llamada a `ReadClients` puedes hacerlo, pero no es necesario. Pero de una manera u otra, la idea es siempre la misma. Debes agregar `async` a la firma del método `FAB_Tab1_Button_Click` y agregar `await` a la llamada a `ReadClients`.

Comment: Agregue el await, tenia que agregar async al método conectado al botón, ahí funciona correctamente, gracias :)

Comment: Para enfasis, y con deseo que halles respuesta más rápido la próxima vez, siempre incluye un [mcve] en tus preguntas para que se entienda el cuadro completo. Si lo hubieras hecho desde un principio, te garantizo que hubieras recibido la respuesta hace 16 horas :)

Comment: Gracias sstan por el consejo, para una próxima agregare mas código, la verdad es que estoy incursionando por c# por primera vez. Gracias a todos :)